# Expand woocommerce single product page functionality with html

Tags: woocommerce, hook

I know it's possible to add checkboxes and other via html to a woocommerce single product description / brief description of product (done that). Is it possible / what are the hooks, in order to save given customer selections and pass the information on to the cart? Customers are able to make choices but unfortunately no information is passed on by woocommerce.

thanks

Comment: You can try [Product Addons](http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-add-ons/)

Comment: hi, thanks for the quick answer helgatheviking. I thought about using addons but that's not possible unfortunately as addons doesn't allow for using images instead as checkboxes (I've already contacted them). As it's farely easy to write the html all I'd need to know is how to link into woocommerce in order to pass information choosen.

Comment: I chose to use the woocommerce gravity forms product add on. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you may add your own HTML and then can use these data to the cart, these hints can be useful for you.
You may use an action

```
"add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'Your_own_function', 10, 2);"

function Your_own_function($cart_data,$pro_id){
    if(isset($_POST['your_checkbox_value'])){
      $item_meta['your_meta_key'] = $_POST['your_checkbox_value'];
      $cart_data ['product_meta'] = array('meta_data' => $item_meta);
    }
    return $cart_data;
}
```

and then you may retrieve these cart item data by using

```
"add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', "custom_get_item_data", 10, 2 );"

function custom_get_item_data($item_meta, $existing_item_meta){
foreach ($existing_item_meta['product_meta'] ['meta_data'] as $key => $val )
    {
    if($key == 'your_meta_key'){

        $item_meta [] = array (
                'name' => __('Custom Name','Text Domain'),
                'value' => stripslashes( $val ),
                );
        }
    }
    return $item_meta;    
}
```